# Using Parse Server on Linux (Webpanel)

Tags: android, parse-platform, debian, parse-server

I have installed `MongoDB` and `Parse` (open Source), all running on my `Linux Server`. How can i create `Application ID`? Does `Parse` have an web interface?!

Answer (score 0):

Application ID can be anything.  I just used a password generator and set it to use only letters and numbers, and the same length string that parse uses.  And yes, there's a web interface to the database: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/

Comment: root@fasfas:~#  git clone markus@**.us:ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard.git
Cloning into 'parse-dashboard'...
markus@**.us's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
markus@**.us's password:

Comment: Don't know what the issue is, I would just download it as a zip file.